# count the number of rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count

How to count the number of rows in mysql database tables with php?

if have in database 5 rows, they number show like this(**bold**):

> > all columns is: **5**
>
> **1** row1
>  **2** row2
>  **3** row3
>  **4** row4
>  **5**
>   row5

Comment: Wait, are you talking about **columns** (id, name, email)? or about **rows** (entries)?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385441/sql-a-numbering-column-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we count them back together? LIKE: 1 2 3 4 5. i not want use of id in column database

```
select list_of_fields,@rn:=@rn+1 as row_num
from table,(select @rn:=0) as r order by id
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use this SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

If you want to know how many rows were returned by another query, you can use the PHP [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function.  (You could also just increment a counter for each row you process, but this function is handy if you need to know the number of records prior to enumerating the results.)

Comment: How do we count them back together? LIKE: `1 2 3 4 5`. **i not want use of id in column database**

Comment: Just maintain an `$index` variable, initialize it to `1`, and increment it (`$index++`) right before the end of your loop.  Then you can use `$index` to get the index of the current result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$result = $this->db->get(<table_name>);
$num_rows = $result->num_rows();
```

`$num_rows` would be the total rows in **table_name**

Then you can just do this

`echo 'The number of rows in table_name is '.$num_rows`;

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `table`
```

The result set would be

```
[count]
-------
5
```

Assuming you have 5 rows.

---

In order to manually count each row and display its index (without using ID), I would do something like

```
$counter = 1;
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `field` FROM `table`');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<b>{$counter}:</b> {$row['field']}";
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: How do we count them back together? LIKE: `1 2 3 4 5`. **i not want use of id in column database**

Comment: You could inscrease a counter in PHP.. Will add an example