# Get number of rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest way to count exact number of rows in a very large table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table)

What query do I use to get the number of rows that share a common specification.
Example: The number of rows where idpost = 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to count exact number of rows in a very large table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table) or [php: count the number of rows in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049153/count-the-number-of-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `COUNT()` documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts WHERE idpost = 3
```

EDIT: Updated according to [dbf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653305/dbf)'s suggestion.. Make sure you distinguish between COUNT(*) and COUNT(1), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221559/944681).

Comment: for performance reasons if a lot of fields exist in the table, I would consider using COUNT(idpost) instead of * (all)

Comment: Both the accepted answer to that linked question (which is specific to [tag:sql-server], not [tag:mysql]) and the manual entry for [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) make clear that `COUNT(*)` is perfectly efficient.  The MySQL manual states: "*`COUNT(*)` is optimized to return very quickly if the `SELECT` retrieves from one table, no other columns are retrieved, and there is no `WHERE` clause.*"

Comment: @dbf: You are incorrect. See this: [What is better in MYSQL count(*) or count(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5180023/548696). Both `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` **perform exactly the same**.

Answer (score 2):

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM some_table WHERE (conditions);
```

In your example:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM some_table WHERE idpost=3;
```

More on **counting rows in MySQL**: [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual: 3.3.4.8. Counting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html)

**EDIT:**

If you were wondering, which way of counting all rows is better (`count(*)` or `count(1)`), see this: [What is better in MYSQL count(*) or count(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5180023/548696).

Answer (score 1):

Consider [learning SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp):

```
select count(*) from mytable where idpost=3
```

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools, for more information, see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: What a piece of crap! A random bump from the street that writes a html page!

Comment: Not quite random bumps, if you visit the page you'll notice the list of authors.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as NumberRows
FROM
    your_table_name_here
WHERE
    idpost = 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

the select count(*) function grabs the number of rows that meet a certain criteria - define that in the where statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html - read here